# Sum different array multidimention

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

anyone can you help me for sum 2 array multidimention, i try some syntax still not work. i use 2 array not 1 array multidimention.

this is the first array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [<-4] => 195
            [-4] => 327
            [-3] => 14
            [-2] => 10
            [-1] => 200
            [0] => 213
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [<-4] => 35
            [-4] => 0
            [-3] => 0
            [-2] => 0
            [-1] => 0
            [0] => 0
        )
)
```

and this is the another array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [<-4] => 0
            [-4] => 0
            [-3] => 0
            [-2] => 0
            [-1] => 0
            [0] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [<-4] => 0
            [-4] => 587
            [-3] => 17
            [-2] => 20
            [-1] => 359
            [0] => 1300
        )
 )
```

and the result same format with that array

Comment: Show me what you did...

Comment: different case, that in 1 multidimentional array, but i have 2 array

Comment: It's the same. It's like saying `echo $a;` is different from `echo $b;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Input**

```
    $array1 = array(
        array('<-4' => 195,'-4' => 327,'-3' => 14,'-2' => 10,'-1' => 200,0 => 213),
        array('<-4' => 35,'-4' => 0,'-3' => 0,'-2' => 0,'-1' => 0,0 => 0)
    );

    $array2 = array(
        array('<-4' => 0,'-4' => 0,'-3' => 0,'-2' => 0,'-1' => 0,0 => 0),
        array('<-4' => 0,'-4' => 587,'-3' => 17,'-2' => 20,'-1' => 359,'0' => 1300)
    );
```

**Solution**

```
    $new = array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($array1);$i++){
        foreach($array1[$i] as $key => $row){
            $new[$i][$key] = $array1[$i][$key]+$array2[$i][$key];
        }
    }
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [<-4] => 195
            [-4] => 327
            [-3] => 14
            [-2] => 10
            [-1] => 200
            [0] => 213
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [<-4] => 35
            [-4] => 587
            [-3] => 17
            [-2] => 20
            [-1] => 359
            [0] => 1300
        )

)
```